# UIImages not displaying in TableView on iPhone, but working in Simulator

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiimage, ios-simulator

I have a UITable View that displays an image in the left hand side of the table cell, and it works fine in the simulator.

Only problem is, once I ran it on my device no images appear. It's just a blank white space.

Have checked that images are added to resource folder for build (which they are) and that capitals etc. match (which they do).

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Code to display images:

```
cell.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[dog types] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];;
    if ( image ) {
        cell.imageView.image = [image imageScaledToSize:CGSizeMake(50, 50)];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem of images, not your code (if they are showing in the simulator). Many times when the images are not in proper format (so that iPhone can understand) and many times the renaming does the bad job (suppose you have changed the extension without changing the format).

You can not compare a simulator with iPhone, because simulator takes advantages of mac-os, so it can do some things that iPhone can't.

So the moral of the story is re-create your images, and check your code with some other images(images that had been showing on device in other projects).

Thanks,

Madhup

Comment: They're PNG files though - and three of them were showing until I cleaned the header files.

Answer (score 0):

Check the iPhone SDK version on which you are running in XCode.

it should be same as the iPhone OS of your iPhone contains.

May be this was the issue...

Comment: Hmm, have checked, doesn't seem to be an issue - both match.

Comment: hi, Graeme

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[dog types] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];;


in this line check the name of image(in debug mode) what you are getting and the image name what is Actually has in resource folder.
it should be mached...

Comment: How would you suggest I do this? Thanks.

Comment: image not displyed without any error means it can't find the image in resource folder...ensure the image name(in debug mode) including image type (*.png) thats the reasone for the "blank white space" which you have said in your Que...
bcose previously i already face this type of problem...

Comment: Yeah what do I do in debug mode though to check?

Comment: check what image name you are getting in your code in line :
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[dog types] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];;

see my other answer

Comment: Yeah but what do I enter in the debug console to check at the breakpoint?

Answer (score 0):

you can have another sollution for getting rounded images if you want to try :

```
UIImageView * roundedView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"wood.jpg"]];
// Get the Layer of any view
CALayer * l = [roundedView layer];
[l setMasksToBounds:YES];
[l setCornerRadius:10.0];

// You can even add a border
[l setBorderWidth:4.0];
[l setBorderColor:[[UIColor blueColor] CGColor]];
```

Comment: Although this works for most `UIView`s, I don't think you can do this with a `UIImageView` due to `UIImageView`'s internal implementation.

Answer (score 0):

replace you code with this and see the log in console :

```
NSString *strImgName = [[dog types] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];

NSLog(@"%@",strImgName);

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:strImgName];
```

and see what you are getting as an image name and mach it with your actual image in resource folder...it should be same (i.e. apple.png = apple.png) including *.extensions

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if image is in the resource group.

> UIImage *cellImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[[dog types] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] ofType:@"png"]];

Comment: if it doesn't work, then must be your images not in proper format. Use preview to change it to desired one.

Answer (score 0):

I know, that's quite an old post now, but I think I have to share what my problem was, somewhere

In my case I had the following code

```
UIImageView *tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"some-Background.png"]];
[tempImageView setFrame:self.tableView.frame];
[self.tableView setBackgroundView:tempImageView];
```

but my Image was named "some-background.png".

In the simulator everything looked fine, but on the phone I got no background. It seems that the simulator is case insensitive, whereas the iPhone is not.